# dynamic default property grails

Tags: grails, default-value, grails-domain-class

i tried to set a default value in a domain-class. i tried this but don't work

```
class myDomainClass{
    int idUser = (${session.user.id}!= null)?${session.user.id}:0; 
}
```

how can i do it?

Comment: what error message do you get

Answer (score 3):

The reason it doesn't work is probably because `session` (the HTTP session) is only available in controllers and GSPs, not domain classes. Instead, define a service that gets the current user and inject this into the domain class

```
class UserService() {

  int currentUserId() {
    GrailsWebRequest webRequest = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
    def session = webRequest.session
    session.user?.id
  }
}

class myDomainClass {    
    static transients = ['userService']

    UserService userService
    int idUser = userService.currentUserId ?: 0
}
```

This implementation accesses the session from a service, which is not recommended, but it should work. of course you could just use the same approach to access the session from the domain class, but this is even less appealing than the solution above

```
class myDomainClass{
    int idUser = {->
        GrailsWebRequest webRequest = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
        def session = webRequest.session
        session.user?.id ?: 0    
    }()
}
```

Comment: if(user){
            session.user = user}     i set the session in login page

Comment: i tried the code posted but don't work i recive a sessionFactory error

Comment: @Cotrariello I fixed an error in my code (I forgot `transients`), please try it again

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager':Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectsmat.AnalisiIZS

Comment: Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectsmat.AnalisiIZS

Answer (score -1):

```
|Running Grails application
Error |
2013-12-18 15:50:17,476 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectsmat.AnalisiIZS
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectsmat.AnalisiIZS
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectsmat.AnalisiIZS
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectsmat.AnalisiIZS
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectsmat.AnalisiIZS
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by InvocationTargetException: null
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NullPointerException: null
->>   19 | <init>    in smat.AnalisiIZS
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Comment: It seems this is the root of your problem:

org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectsmat.AnalisiIZS

Comment: and what means? what i can do?

Comment: Showing us the source code of this class would be a good start

Answer (score -1):

class AnalisiIZS {

```
Campione campione;
Date dataAnalisiCampione;
String specieIsolata1;   
String codiceIsolato1; 
String specieIsolata2;  
String codiceIsolato2;  
String specieIsolata3;  
String codiceIsolato3; 
String specieIsolata4;  
String codiceIsolato4;
String nomeUser;

static constraints = {   

    dataAnalisiCampione(blank:true)
    specieIsolata1(blank:true)
    codiceIsolato1(blank:true)
    specieIsolata2(blank:true)
    codiceIsolato2(blank:true)
    specieIsolata3(blank:true)
    codiceIsolato3(blank:true)
    specieIsolata4(blank:true)
    codiceIsolato4(blank:true)
    campione(blank:true)
    nomeUser(display:false)

}

String toString(){
    return dataAnalisiCampione;
}
```